# Using mutt to fetch email from hotmail?

Tags: email, mutt

OK so I have mutt installed. But can't properly configure my hotmail acccount.
I need some sample for hotmail configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mutt can *optionally* be built with [SMTP](http://www.mutt.org/doc/devel/manual.html#smtp), [POP3](http://www.mutt.org/doc/devel/manual.html#pop) and [IMAP4](http://www.mutt.org/doc/devel/manual.html#imap) support. Most mainstream distributions probably do build it that way.

It looks like Hotmail allows POP3 access to e-mail, which certainly makes things easier. In that case, you'd probably be looking at setting up [`$pop_host`](http://www.mutt.org/doc/devel/manual.html#pop) and perhaps its friends if you want to use only mutt.

Alternatively, you can use a separate program such as fetchmail, getmail, gotmail or similar. These should be provided in your Linux distribution's repositories. Doing so might be better since it will allow you to run the mail fetching automatically in the background at a given interval through e.g. cron. Depending on specifics you might need a mail delivery agent (MDA); procmail will normally do quite nicely and works well in combination with mutt. I'm using the combination of mutt, fetchmail and procmail myself, not with Hotmail but to filter mail downloaded over POP3.

Assuming that Hotmail does support plain old POP3 without any weirdness, setting up getting mail from there should be little different from setting up getting mail from any other POP3 account, which is a basic use case of anything that downloads mail from a remote account (meaning there should be examples in the documentation).